# Trailing space while using "headertemplate" in asp gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which is bounded as

```
<asp:GridView
    runat="server"
    ID="gvShipDetails"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    OnRowDataBound="gvShipDetails_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Ship name
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox class="search_textbox" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Width="100%">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("VesselName")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The problem is the finally rendered html table td is rendered as

```
<td>       sample  vessel name    </td>
```

A lot of spaces inside td.How is this possible.
If I replace this bound code as

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="vessel name" DataField="vesselname" />
```

Then html is renderd as `<td>sample vessel name<td>`

Why is it so? I wanted to use headertemplate and i wanted to avoid these trailing spaces. How to do it

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Maybe the text tried to fit itself in the whole textbox space available?

Comment: This has nothing to do with textbox. Textbox is just for filtering the gridview using jquery seach plugin

Comment: tried `<ItemTemplate><%#Eval("VesselName")%></ItemTemplate>`?

Comment: Yes. When i use a jquery edit plugin for editing cell details. the space is showing up. Ineed this to avoid

Answer (score 0):

As Naveen suggested Doing

```
<ItemTemplate><%#Eval("VesselName")%></ItemTemplate>
```

Solved my issue and the reason for this is unknown for me

Comment: That was what @naveen suggested, so he should probably get the credit for the answer

Comment: @Robert_Junior, the problem is with the whitespace in your html. here is a great plugin to help you with it. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a204e29b-1778-4dae-affd-209bea658a59

Comment: @naveen didn't noticed ur answer with full attention.
thx for the answer